# I need to write a code in xagents to pull data from .csv file to lotus notes

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a requirement where I need to write a code in SSJS to pull data from .csv file to Lotus Notes.

I searched alot online & found code for exporting but no luck for import code.

I am new to xPages & SSJS so any reference will be highly helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

The below link is from TLCC they have some good learning resources. this one walks through how to import data from a sample CSV file. hope it helps.

http://www.tlcc.com/admin/Tips.nsf/0/513dfd72d03a9fe38525718b006fa5a8?OpenDocument&TableRow=8.1

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the link is lotusscript code for export to .csv. I was looking for the same in Server Side JavaScript.

Comment: I know you where looking for SSJS but you could easily put this is an agent and then call the agent through SSJS, give you the best of both worlds

Answer (score 0):

I would use `java.util.Scanner`. It can scan a file for you and rip it into pieces:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(cFile);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
String curLine = scanner.nextLine().trim();
    this.processRow(curLine);
}

private void processRow(String workString) {
     Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(workString);
 lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
     // .next goes through the elements
     lineScanner.next();

}
```

Let us know how it goes. A few interesting challenges you might face, depending on the structure of your CSV file (this is why you might need to do some elaborate code here)

It could be:
number,string,string,"String with , inside",String,number 
So if you only "escape" the String with , inside you have trouble. If all Strings are in "" then you need to Strip these and you have multiple delimiters to deal with:
Number,"String   Number,Number "String","String" String",Number
so it gets a little complicated and you might want to use the byte array and a state to go through the individual lines.

Alternatively you can give [OpenCVS](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) a shot

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was looking for the code in SSJS. By the way the challenges you described are really helpful for writing the code from Scratch.

Comment: Afreen, don't bother, there are too many edge cases. the OpenCVS takes care of them and you can use it in SSJS too